# Using Variables in SQL Query Run Through Code

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I want to pass a variable to a sql string being executed via C#.  I am hitting a compile error tho, and I am not perfectly sure how to end my sql statement with my variable.  This is the line of code that I have

```
string Fire = "Database";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectSQL);
SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = Main_'" + Fire + "') DROP VIEW dbo.Main_'" + Fire + "');
```

The errors are

```
Newline in constant
; expected
) expected
```

What do I need to do so that this becomes a valid statement?

Comment: You're treating the `SqlCommand` type like a method. You need to instantiate it with `new`. There's a bazillion (maybe more!) examples of how to create a `SqlCommand` object on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing double quote.  See below.

```
SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = Main_'" + Fire + "') DROP VIEW dbo.Main_'" + Fire + "'**"**);
```